# variable not defined in java try catch return statement

Tags: java, return

It is showing temp_lib is not declared, but it is already declared.

Library temp_lib is already declared after try and return, temp_lib is written at last but also it is asking for me to initialize the variables.

```
int numAdded=0;
File inputfile;

inputfile = new File("export_Library.txt");
try {
    Library temp_lib;
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(inputfile);
    System.out.println("processing a library...");
    String name=inputScanner.nextLine();
    int capacity=Integer.parseInt(inputScanner.next());
    temp_lib=new Library(name,capacity);

    LibraryItem item=new LibraryItem();
    while(inputScanner.hasNextLine()){
        item.setTitle(inputScanner.nextLine());
        item.setID_code(inputScanner.nextLine());
        item.setYearOfPublication(Integer.parseInt(inputScanner.nextLine()));
        if(inputScanner.next()=="1")
        {
            item.setOnLoan(true);
        }
        else
        {
            item.setOnLoan(false);
        }
        item.setReplacementCost(inputScanner.nextDouble());
    }   
    inputScanner.close();  
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IO Exception reading shapes from file"+e);
    e.printStackTrace() ;
    //return temp_lib;  
}
return temp_lib;
```

Comment: `temp_lib` is declared *within* the `try` block, and you're trying to use it *outside* the `try` block. (Perhaps some proper indentation would make it clearer.)

Answer (score 3):

`Library temp_lib;` must be before the try-catch block in order to be in scope after the try-catch block.

```
Library temp_lib = null; // you must give it an initial value, or the code
                         // won't compile 
try {
   ...
}
catch (..) {
   ...
}
return temp_lib;
```

Comment: @Nachinne_Manche did you give it an initial value? (see edit)